# Polygon skew algorithm

Tags: algorithm, geometry, shadow

What algorithm can I use to skew a polygon?
Like skewing the following:

```
 ____
|   _|
|__|
```

To bottom right will yield

```
 ____
|    \
|     \
 \    _|
  \__|
```

its like a shadow cast. I thought about taking every line and making a parallelogram with it and its corresponding line in the skewed position and then union all of these, but that looks a bit brute to do and will take a lot of time.
Is there a better algorithm for this? I already have code for all polygon boolean operations if its needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this algorithm I just thought up will do it:

Classify every line in the polygon as to whether it is more facing-top-left or facing-bottom-right (or exactly along the skew-direction line).

Then, for each vertex:

- If it joins two top-left lines or a top-left line and an exactly-aligned line, then leave it be.
- If it joins two bottom-right lines or a bottom-right line and an exactly-aligned line, then move it by the skew distance.
- If it joins a top-left and bottom-right line, then split it into two vertices, one moved and one not.

  This step may cause a self-intersection (such as if the vertex was concave and facing bottom left), in which case discard the two vertices and join the two existing lines with a vertex at their intersection point.

Comment: I did not understand the self-intersection avoiding step

Comment: If you don't do that extra part, you will get a triangular self-intersection at some concavities. All you need to do is "fill in the hole", which happens to work out to being the intersection. I suggest implementing the rest of the algorithm, and you'll see what the problem and solution is.

Comment: I implemented this and its working great and very fast. about the self-intersection all I need to do is draw the triangles with 'positive' winding instead of the default 'odd' winding.

Comment: I'm not certain that handling intersection that way won't have some edge cases. Great to hear the algorithm works.